# React, Enzyme async lifecycle function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, mobx

I have an async `componentDidMount` function on my component, which makes an API call and updates a `mobx` store. The componnet has a `@observer` annotation.

I have mocked the API, but I'm having trouble - I can't figure out how to wait on that lifecycle method in my test:

```
 it("Magick", async () => {
    const comp = await mount(<Comp/>); // -- no point of await here

    // await comp.instance().componentDidMount(); -- should work, even if function is called wtice
    // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // -- smelly and prone to crashing

    expect(Axios.post).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(MobX.value).toBe(-1);

    comp.unmount();
});
```

Component snippet:

```
 componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await AxiosWrapper.GetValue();

        if (result) {
            const errors = Parser.getErrors(result);
            if (errors) {
                console.log(errors);
            } else {
                MobX.value = Parser.getValue(result)
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Axios wrapper method:

```
static async GetValue() {
    return await Axios.post(...);
}
```

The only solution I've found is adding a timeout, but that is not acceptable. Any other solution I've found is not working - any ideas?

Comment: Please, provide the code you're testing. It's relevant.

Comment: @estus Updated the question, I guess it has something to do with the way I've written the lifecycle function.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the component testable, there should be a promise to chain. The problem with this component is that `componentDidMount` is instance method, it cannot be spied or mocked before the component is instantiated. Instead, it should be:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  ...
}
```

Then it can be spied on class prototype:

```
const cdmSpy = jest.spyOn(Comp.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
const comp = mount(<Comp/>);
await cdmSpy.mock.results[0].value;
...
```

Alternatively, `componentDidMount` can be called manually and tested together with Enzyme `disableLifecycleMethods` option.

Comment: Thanks, but the spy approach gives me: `TypeError: object[methodName].mockImplementation is not a function`

Comment: Made `componentDidMount` call another async function. Mounted the component, await on the method call and it works fine, odd though.

Comment: I'm not aware of the circumstances under which this error could occur. I'd expect it to work. Possibly buggy Jest version or something. Make sure you fixed `componentDidMount` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @estus to pointing me into the right direction.

I fixed it by:

- made `componentDidMount` call a separate function `other`.
- spyOn `other`, `await spy.mock.results[0].value;`

If I tried to spy directly on `componentDidMount`, I got an error: `TypeError: object[methodName].mockImplementation is not a function`.

It may be because the component in question has `@observer` and `@withNamespaces` decorators on it.